# What's the difference between casting an int to a string and the ToString() method in C#

Tags: c#

What's the difference between casting an Int to a string and the ToString() method ?

For example :-

```
int MyInt = 10;
label1.Text = (string)MyInt;       // This Doesn't Work
label1.Text = MyInt.ToString();    // but this does.
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, `ToString()` is just a method call which returns a string. It's defined in `object` so it's always valid to call on anything (other than a null reference).

The cast operator can do one of four things:

- A predefined conversion, e.g. `int` to `byte`
- An execution time reference conversion which may fail, e.g. casting `object` to `string`, which checks for the target object being an appropriate type
- A user-defined conversion (basically calling a static method with a special name) which is known at compile-time
- An unboxing conversion which may fail, e.g. casting `object` to `int`

In this case, you're asking the compiler to emit code to convert from `int` to `string`. None of the above options apply, so you get a compile-time error.

Comment: Looks like your rep will be 50K today! Advanced congratulations!

Comment: :)
To add to the answer, in C#, int is an alias to the class Int32. So MyInt is an object of type Int32 which does not support casing to String because it does not derive from it.

Comment: @daanish, Int32 isn't a class in C#, it's a struct.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why int to string is not predefined? does it have anything to do with culture dependent format, perhaps?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: No, it would just be an odd sort of conversion to include directly into the language - it's much better suited as a normal method call. Note that there *is* an implicit conversion (which uses ToString) if you use string concatenation involving an `int`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. but this is still puzzling to me. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by *odd*, especially since there is implicit conversion.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: No, there isn't an implicit conversion. You can't write `string x = 10;` for example - that *would* be valid if there's an implicit conversion. Basically, C# provides conversions between types which are very similar, or where one can be regarded as a superset of the other, e.g. between int and long, float and double. Numbers and strings are really very different things.

Answer (score 9):

The difference is that with the cast, you ask the compiler to assume that the int is in fact a string, which is not the case.

With the ToString(), you ask for a string representation for the int, which is in fact a string :)

Answer (score 1):

Um, ToString() is calling a method that returns a string representation of the integer.

When you cast, you are not returning a representation, you are saying that you want to reference the same object (well, value-type in this case) but you want to reference it as a different type.

A cast will only succeed if the type you are casting to (target type) is the same type as the object being cast or the target type is a superclass or interface of the cast object.

It is actually possible to do conversion in a cast providing the the source or target type declare implicit or explicit conversions, but the Int32 type does not do this for the String target type.

Answer (score 1):

The .ToString() method is a method implemented on the System.Object type (from which all .NET types derive) and can be overridden on specific derived types.

Therefore the "int" type has it's own .ToString() method which knows all about ints, and how to convert them to a string representation.

With the (string)myint explicit cast, you are asking the compiler to forcefully convert/cast one type to another (in this case, an int into a string).  It fails because the compiler says that a string and an int are incompatible types.

So, the explicit cast fails because the compiler says that an int *is not* a string, however the .ToString() call succeeds because the int type says that it's value *can be represented* as a string, and does so!

Answer (score 0):

The `ToString()` method is one of the most usefull methods in programming and many other languages, such as Java, have the exact same method implemented at the `Object` level.

You can define your own and the signature in C# must always be this:

```
public override string ToString()
```

Which means  this method will override the one define in the Object-class and returns a string. Inside, you manipulate your string in whichever way you want and then return the result.

Furthermore, the specific reason you can use ToString on that integer is because within C#, integers are all instances of the Struct `Int32`.
 Seeing as `Int32` is at the same level of a class, it can have its own methods, one of which is ToString().

Answer (score 0):

One more thing never use .ToString() if you think the object might be null or your application will crach example :

//Emulates the problem that might happen
object obj = null;
    obj.ToString();