# Redirect page on JasperException

Tags: java, jsp, exception, servlets, redirect

**Main.jsp**

```
String name = session.getAttribute("name").toString();
if (name == "" || name == null) {

    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");

}
```

When user access this page by login, there is no problem in main  page. But when user want to try to access the page without login, I want to redirect the page to index.jsp, but

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /main.jsp
```

How redirect to index.jsp

Comment: I suspect that the `name` attribute in the session would be `null` in this case. I don't know this framework in the slightest bit, but I think you are encountering a NullReferenceException. The attribute `name` is null, and you can't use instance methods (`toString()`) of objects which are null. In your case the `name == null` check is completely useless since it can't check for null before the null reference exception happens! My hint: Check `session.getAttribute("name")` against null before executing `toString()` on it.

Comment: I don't write java, but can you not just use try...catch on the toString() line? Then on the catch just do your redirect?

Comment: @JasperMogg That would work too, but it's kind of like a workaround on the lines of "errors? Just try-catch them!" Also as far as I know try-catching is a lot more expensive on the CPU than just doing a check against null if all you're catching is a null reference exception.

Comment: Fair comment dude, thanks for replying :-)

Answer (score 0):

**change**

```
String name = session.getAttribute("name").toString();
```

**TO**

```
String name = (String)session.getAttribute("name");
```

Comment: I don't get it either, it might be a framework quirk that the `Attribute`s are castable to empty strings ;-). Who knows?

Comment: @JasperMogg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709263/whats-the-difference-between-casting-an-int-to-a-string-and-the-tostring-meth This is work for me ! Thanks Both FM

Comment: @JasperMogg Nice link for you by Shahid Ghafoor (Above)

Comment: oh dear @sinni800 session.getAttribute("name"); returning object and (String)session.getAttribute("name"); means to cast object to String not attribute is casting to empty strings! http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html