# Comparison between button content and string

Tags: c#, wpf, string

I'm doing a wpf application which contains a virtual keyboard, when I click into the CapsLock button I have this notification :

`Possibility of comparing references involuntary for a comparison of values​​, cast the left hand side to type 'string'`

in this line :

```
if (btnVK_A.Content == "a")
     btnVK_A.Content = "A";
else
     btnVK_A.Content = "a";
```

I did the casting of `btnVK_A.Content` to string but the notification is still appear. So how can I fix this ?

Comment: Just to be clear, you did `if ((String)btnVK_A.Content == "a")`?

Comment: i try `if ((String)btnVK_A.Content == "a")` and `if (btnVK_A.Content.ToString() == "a")`

Comment: Which type does `btnVK_A.Content` return?

Comment: @Shaharyar the type is object

Comment: @Lamloumi That's the return type, but since `object` is the base type for all classes, it's not necessarily the type that is stored. Which type of object is inserted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
if ((btnVK_A.Content as string) == "a")
```

**Difference between `as` keyword and `ToString()`:**

The two are intended for different purposes. The `ToString` method of any object is supposed to return a string representation of that object. Casting is quite different, and the `as` key word performs a conditional cast, as has been said. The `as` key word basically says "get me a reference of this type to that object if that object is this type" while `ToString` says "get me a string representation of that object". The result may be the same in some cases but the two should never be considered interchangeable because, as I said, they exist for different purposes. If your intention is to cast then you should always use a cast, NOT `ToString`.

Comment: yes thanks it works now, can you explain why only this casting resolve the problem?

Comment: @Shaharyar but why didn't direct cast work either? (`(String)btnVK_A.Content`). I'm suspecting `btnVK_A.Content` is not a String, so casting with `as` will get rid of the warning, but will always result in `null`

Comment: @DavidS. check out this same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709263/whats-the-difference-between-casting-an-int-to-a-string-and-the-tostring-meth

Comment: @Shaharyar I'm not talking about `ToString()`. If direct cast fails then `btnVK_A.Content` isn't a string. But `as`-cast doesn't give an exception but just returns `null`

Answer (score 0):

Try to first accept the key using 'var' by casting it. 
then check what you want.

var b=(string)btnVK_A.Content;

if (b == "a")
     btnVK_A.Content = "A";
else
     btnVK_A.Content = "a";

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using btnVK_A.Content.ToString(), or (string) btnVK_A.Content? Since the Button Content property is of the object type, the compiler will give you a warning if you don't cast or convert it to string before comparing it.

Comment: i did these two versions but the same notification