# why isn't there a explicit typecast to string in c#

Tags: c#

why doesn't c# consist of explicit typecast to string as shown below

```
string s=(string)3;
```

Why can't the compiler convert 3 into string and give to s when it is possible to assign double value to integer by truncating the double value and assigning to integer variable

Comment: Might be because there is a fundamental difference between `string` and `int`. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709263/whats-the-difference-between-casting-an-int-to-a-string-and-the-tostring-meth) is a Link to shed some light on that.

Comment: You can do a  `string s = Convert.ToString(3);`

Comment: @ShawnYan - or just `string s = 3.ToString();`

Comment: I think the question is not "why cannot I do X", it is more about "why compiler doesn't support doing X". And I can't find that great answer that is like "even if it seems simple, it would take hundreds of man-hours to implement and the feature is not important enough to justify that".

Comment: @Corak yep there's a lot of workaround for this conversion , but remember all will eventually call `.ToString() `

Comment: There's far too much stringly-typed code written as it is (where people use `string`s to pass data around when more appropriate data types are also available). It's already quite easy to convert anything into a string, we shouldn't be seeking ways to make it easier.

Comment: Or just `s = 3 + ""`